# Display results containing a field in common in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a table view that looks something like this.

```
ID   Name    Gender  Country
1    Joe       M        UK
2    Anna      F        UK
3    Karl      M        UK
4    Jane      F        US
5    Drake     M        US
```

If I search for M (Gender), I get this result.

```
ID   Name    Gender  Country
1    Joe       M        UK
3    Karl      M        UK
5    Drake     M        US
```

But I only want one result per country and then I'd like to add total number of Males in that country and pass it to ViewData["Total"], as shown below.

```
ID   Name    Gender  Country   Total
1    Joe       M        UK       2
5    Drake     M        US       1
```

At the moment, I only have a simple code. I would appreciate any ideas on this.

```
Public ActionResults Gender(string search)
{
    return view = db.Gender_View.Where(Gender_View => Gender_View.gender == search).ToList(); 
}
```

Comment: You need to use a `.GroupBy(x => x.Country)` and then count the results into a `Total` property

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by following code. Need to apply group by on country.

```
Public ActionResults Gender(string search)
{
    var result = db.Gender_View.Where.Where(x => x.gender = search)
    .GroupBy(x => x.Country)
    .Select(x => new
    {
        Country = x.Key,
        Count = x.Count()
    }).ToList();

    ViewBag.Result = result;
    return View();
}
```